# Well-definedness of Picard operator

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The Picard operator $P$ associated with the diﬀerential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt} = F(t,x)\quad\quad (t,x)\in U \subseteq C×C^n, F \in O^n(U).$$ and the initial value $(t_0,z_0)$, is the operator $f\rightarrow Pf$ deﬁned by the integral formula $$(Pf)(s,z) = z +  \int_{t_0}^{s}F(t,f(t,z))dt$$Denote by $L_0$ and $L_1$ the bounds for the magnitude of $F$ and its Lipschitz constant in $U:$ for any $(t,x),(t,x_0)∈U, |F(t,z)|\leqslant L_0, |F(t,z)−F(t,z_0)|\leqslant L_1|z−z_0|$. Denote by M the subspace of the space $A^n(D_\epsilon)$ (linear space of functions holomorphic in the polydisk and continuous on its closure) which consists of the functions satisfying the additional inequality $|f(t,z)−z|\leqslant L_0|t−t_0|$.

Here's a part of proof involving this operator I don't understand:
Explicit majorizing of the integral shows that $$|Pf(s,z)−z| \leqslant L_0 \int_{t_0}^{s}|dt|\leqslant L_0|s−t_0|\leqslant L_0\epsilon,$$so if $\epsilon$ is chosen sufficiently small, the operator P is well deﬁned on M and maps this space into itself.
How to see the operator is well defined from the above calculation?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the space where $P$ is defined. In particular, what is $M$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have edited the post.

Comment: What is the first meaning of $L_0$? Do you also have $|f(t,x)|<L_0$? Is $L_0$ additionally a Lipschitz constant in $x$-direction?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, $L_0$ is a bound for $F( t, x)$, I have edited the post again. Thanks.

Comment: What is $z$, what is the role of $z$ in $f$, what is the relation of $z$ and $z_0$, what is the final claim of the theorem?